# EF 4.3 Code First Migrations - Seed per migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

have recently started using Code First Migrations and was wanting to seed data in each **Up** method.

is this possible?

Ie.

1. Create database table
2. Fill with data

for Drop:

1. Delete data from joining table
2. delete table

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible but you must do it through executing SQL commands. Use `Sql` method in both `Up` and `Down` methods of your migration to execute `INSERT` and `DELETE` SQL commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
public partial class DBInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DBContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(DBContext context)
    {

        var cfg = new Migrations.Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(cfg);

        List<string> pendingMigrations = new List<string>(migrator.GetPendingMigrations());

        foreach (string migration in pendingMigrations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updating Migration:" + migration);
            migrator.Update(migration);
            Console.WriteLine("Updated Migration:" + migration);

            if (migration.Contains("AddMyProperty"))
            {
                // seed data codes
                context.SaveChanges();
            }                
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question. It's not even an answer, just code.